# Using static non-member vs. non-static member variables in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, member

Let's say that I have a function that gets called periodically. The function gets a value as parameter and I want to compare it to the value that was received during the earlier function call, ie. the value needs to be memorized. Should I use static non-member variable or a non-static member variable for that purpose? What are the advantages and disadvantages for both approaches?

As a static non-member approach I mean something like

```
class foo {
    public:
        void func(int value) {
            static int lastValue;
            if (value > lastValue) {
                doSomething(value)
            }
            lastValue = value;
    };
};
```

And as a non-static member variable something like

```
class foo {
    private:
        int lastValue_;

    public:
        void func(int value) {
             if (value > lastValue_) {
                 doSomething(value)
             }
             lastValue_ = value;
        };
};
```

Comment: if `lastValue` is used only in function I think it's reasonable to use static approach

Comment: Yes, in this case it is used only in a single function.

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov In that case, all instances of `class foo` will share the same `lastValue` via`func()`. Whereas with the non-static member variable, each instance has its own memoisation. This may or may not be required here, but it's a very important difference to note.

Comment: @underscore_d So it is safe to use only when only a single instance of `foo` is existing? In that case, should it be a singleton?

Comment: It's not in any way "unsafe" to have multiple instances accessing a shared variable, which is what a `static` member nets you. If, instead, by "safe" you mean you want to restrict access to a single instance, then yes, a singleton or some variant would ensure this. However, equally, in practice a singleton pattern kinda defeats the point of using member `static`s for anything except the `get_instance()` :P

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should add some initialisation of the non-`static` `lastValue_` member variable - as is you have undefined behaviour.  (The `static` function-local variable will be initialised to `0`, which may or may not suit you.)

> What are the advantages and disadvantages for both approaches?

- Using a non-static member variable means the program can create as many `foo` instances as they like, and they'll operate independently.  No two threads should access the same `foo` object without synchronisation, but they can access `foo` instances that other threads aren't accessing, including any thread specific `foo` instances.
- Having a non-static member variable can also make things easier to unit- and regression-test, as simply creating a new object will "reset" the state, whereas with a `static` function-local variable there's no easy way to restore the starting value (you have to hack in a function argument that requests that).
- The function-local `static` variable does have the advantage of being more localised in the sense of accessibility from other code, making it clear it's only relevant to the `func` function.  Using the tightest possible variable scope is normally desirable, but here this is massively less important than the points above.
- More generally - in many ways the function-local `static` variable has the same issues as global variables or singletons - google will turn those up pretty smartly.